# AsyncControllerActionInvoker equivalent in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, controlleractioninvoker

I've been trying to migrate a project from MVC to Core 3.1 and have been slightly stuck.

The class (in mvc) uses `AsyncControllerActionInvoker` and overrides the `InvokeAction` method. Since this isn't compatible in netcore 3.1, is there a way to replicate this pattern in netcore 3.1?

Bellow a sample code:

```
public class ActionInvoker : AsyncControllerActionInvoker
{
    public override bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
    {
        this.InvokeActionWithActionResult(controllerContext, actionName); 
        // This custom function calls other methods in the controller such as BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters and EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can add async action like: `public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int? id)`

Comment: Will that pull every invoke action just like in framework ?

Comment: No, it will not. It will simply execute action method. Action attributes, controller's OnActionExecuting etc will all be left out. :(